# Android Volley JsonObjectRequest format: http://localhost:8080/xy?param1=1&param2=2

Tags: android, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

I'm trying to make a Volley JsonObjectRequest (GET) sending Parameters in the following format:

http://localhost:8080/xy?param1=1&param2=2

My Problem is, I should get a Response-Code 200 (OK), if param1 is "1" and param2 is "2". But I always get the wrong Response Code. 
So I think, the request is sending in the wrong format.

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
            params.put("param1", "1");
            params.put("param2", "2");
            JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
                    (Request.Method.GET, "http://localhost:8080/xy", new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });

            // Access the RequestQueue through your singleton class.
            QueueSingleton.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(jsObjRequest);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you're providing your JsonObject(params) as the body of the request, which is incorrect.  I don't think Volley will append your provided JSON object to your URL for you on a GET request...so you need to do that yourself.

Get rid of adding the post body, and append the params manually on the URL using [Uri.Builder.appendQueryParameter(key, value)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.Builder.html#appendQueryParameter(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

Because you use **GET** method, try to append the params with the url like

```
int param1Value = 1, param2Value = 2;
String url = "http://localhost:8080/xy?param1=" + param1Value + "&param2=" + param2Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int p1=1;
int p2= 2;

string url= "http://localhost:8080/xy?param1="+p1+"&param2="+p2;
```

put this url insted of url you are using..